# Merge multiple state changes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Ajax based app that I am trying to port to React. There is a slider, and the app fetches an image from the server depending on the value of the slider. If the user moves the slider very fast, this generates a lot of requests, faster than they can be served. What I do in this case is:

- If there is no current request, send one to the server
- If a request is pending, don't send one (the old image is still shown)

  - When the pending request finishes, *compare the current value of the slider with what we just fetched*. If there is a mismatch, try to fetch a new image (go to be the beginning of the algorithm).

The actual code also caches images locally, but that is not important for this question.

I have this almost translated to React. I have an outer component that sends the Ajax requests depending on its props, and an inner component that displays the results. If a request is pending, I can stop making new requests. What is missing is the part in italic above. The user stops dragging, the last request comes in, *I compare with the currently selected value*, and if there is a mismatch, send another request. It seems to be against the idea of React to query the state of a component (the slider) somewhere random in an async handler - values should rahter be passed down.

How do I solve this in react? (The specific problem of refreshing a component that is stale, or the general problem of dealing with a lot of user input that generates HTTP requests.)

Comment: Are you using Redux? It handles the state changes automatically

Comment: No, at least not yet. I'm just getting started, but I have to take a look at it!

Comment: Yes you should I'm also a starter, and read about auto state handling

Comment: Can you show any codes you try?